# Standard Answers - E.g. Solve Issues Caused by a specific Plugin

Tags: discussion

What do you think? While scanning the lists of unanswered questions and the regular one, I've seen multiple that are most likely related to some incompatibilities caused by an add-on (plugin, theme) which highly like breaks a core feature or is just in the way.

The standard procedure I'm aware of to track such issues down is to deactivate stuff and then to look which one is causing the issue. Example question:

nextpage tag is not working for some posts: 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2357/nextpage-tag-is-not-working-for-some-posts

I would like to have a central place somewhere on the site to link to to give users some hints at hand how to track down things.

This probably has been asked already. Next to that, I would like to know if it's wished to answer such question or to close them as it's more or less most likely a too specific question by someone to be properly answered here.

I generally prefer more common questions so the community can benefit from answers at large. But I have no problem to be polite so while closing answers to leave a kind of predefined repsonse in there (maybe a link to a wiki page) so that there is actually some direction for those who have asked. And probably additionally to explain which kind of questions we want or not.

See/Compare Should WordPress Answers be a “Solve my Specific Problem” site?: 
[Should WordPress Answers be a "Solve my Specific Problem" site?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/should-wordpress-answers-be-a-solve-my-specific-problem-site)

Comment: *"I would like to have a central place somewhere on the site to link to to give users some hints at hand how to track down things."* +1000!

Comment: Disclosure: I just clicked my own question wondering who asked it. I'll correct the capitalization of words in the title now. And I should not text so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe also related: [What WordPress-specific questions do we want in the FAQs?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91/what-wordpress-specific-information-should-we-have-in-the-faqs) That question got a bit side-tracked because we were not clear about what a "FAQ" was: is it a "best of WordPress Answers", the most frequently asked questions about WordPress, or asked about this site?

Also, new users get [a mandatory advice page before asking questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask-advice). If we have a good proposal, it is probably possible to get the content replaced with something more WordPress-specific.

The easiest way would be to link to some selected questions we create ourselves, just like we created the ["do not modify core files"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/what-are-some-reasons-why-you-should-not-hack-wordpress-core-files) question ([twice, even](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files)). Since this requires no extra UI to keep it up to date (only when a new question gets added), this has probably the best chance of getting accepted by the site owners. This can also end up in the sidebar of the homepage, [like MSO has](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Although I must say that I don't really like the format of, for example, ["Objective Best Practices for Plugin Development"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development): I would prefer one edited "meta-answer" on top, that collects all good answers in a logical structure. Now it jumps around too much to my taste.